# Let listview know that contentprovider is updated

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm having a listview that shows my model items that I filled with the contentprovider (inbox). Now when I'm in my broadcastreceiver and I get an update I would like to let the listview know that he must update his List off models and show it.

I've seen that you can do this with notifyChanged but I can't find a good example.

Can someone help me out on this?

EDIT:

SMSBroadcastReceiver:

```
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            final SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < pdus.length; i++) {
                messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            }

            if (messages.length < 0) {
                return;
            }

            SmsMessage sms = messages[0];
            String body = "";
            String sender = sms.getOriginatingAddress().toString();
            Long time_rcv = sms.getTimestampMillis();

            try {
                if (messages.length == 1 || sms.isReplace()) {
                    body = sms.getDisplayMessageBody();
                } else {
                    StringBuilder bodyText = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
                        bodyText.append(messages[i].getMessageBody());
                    }
                    body = bodyText.toString();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            ContentValues smsValues = new ContentValues();
            smsValues.put("address", sender);
            smsValues.put("body", body);
            smsValues.put("date_sent", time_rcv);
            context.getContentResolver().insert(BlacklistConstants.smsInboxUri, smsValues);
```

From here I want to the let my fragment know that there is a new sms added. 
Thats the .insert gives me back.

This is the fragment this function fills my smsList that contains my models.

```
private void fetchBox(Conversations smsConversation, String thread_id, Uri threadUri) {
    //Cursor smsInThreads = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(threadUri, null, "thread_id = ?", new String[]{thread_id}, null);

    CursorLoader cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(), threadUri,
            null, // the columns to retrieve (all)
            "thread_id = ?", // the selection criteria (none)
            new String[]{thread_id}, // the selection args (none)
            null // the sort order (default)
    );

    Cursor smsInThreads = cursorLoader.loadInBackground();

    if (smsInThreads.moveToFirst()) {
        smsConversation.setNumber(smsInThreads.getString(smsInThreads.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
        for (int x = 0; x < smsInThreads.getCount(); x++) {
            smsObjects msg = new smsObjects();
            msg.setBody(smsInThreads.getString(smsInThreads.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
            msg.setNumber(smsInThreads.getString(smsInThreads.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
            msg.setId(smsInThreads.getString(smsInThreads.getColumnIndexOrThrow("_id")));
            msg.setTimeStampReceived(smsInThreads.getString(smsInThreads.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date_sent")));
            smsConversation.addTextMessage(msg);
            smsInThreads.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    //smsList.add(smsConversation);
    smsInThreads.close();
}
```

And finally this is my custom adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Conversations> {

private String TAG = ListAdapter.class.getName();

private final Context context;
private final List<Conversations> smsList;

public ListAdapter(Context context, List<Conversations> smsList) {
    super(context, R.layout.sms_inbox, smsList);
    this.context = context;
    this.smsList = smsList;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sms_inbox, parent, false);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.senderNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.smsNumberText);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    holder.senderNumber.setText(smsList.get(position).getNumber());

    return convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView senderNumber;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return smsList != null ? smsList.size() : 0;
}
```

}

Now I don't know how to easy let the fragment know that there is a new insert and that the listview needs to update his model and show it.

I did this in the past like this:

```
  Uri newSms = context.getContentResolver().insert(BlacklistConstants.smsInboxUri, smsValues);
            Log.d(TAG,newSms.toString());

            Intent smsReceiveIntent = new Intent(BlacklistConstants.smsFilter);
            smsReceiveIntent.putExtra("newSMS",newSms);
            context.sendBroadcast(smsReceiveIntent);
```

And then on my fragment I listened to that intent and added it to the smsList and then did notifyDataChanged. But I think there is a better way not?

Comment: You have to notify the adapter that's backing the listView. adapter.setNotifyOnChange(true) tells the adapter that operations like swapCursor should trigger an update. Your listView will change following the change in the adapter.

Comment: To request an update on the adapter use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after you actually change the data in the adapter.

Comment: But then I still need to fire an broadcast from my broadcastreceiver to notify in my mainfragment that the data is changed then insert the new data en then call notifyDataChanged. Whats the profit of contentproviders then :s?

Comment: Show the code you have implemented, so that others can help

Comment: Post some code.
ContentProvider let you use `CursorLoader`s and let other applications access your data (if you say so). Also, ContentProvider let you listen for changes on the data, SQLite doesn't do that (if I'm right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by starting an intent in the onreceive and then in the main listen to that intent and update the list.

In the onreceive:

```
          Intent smsReceiveIntent = new Intent(BlacklistConstants.smsFilter);
            smsReceiveIntent.putExtra("newSMS",newSms.toString());
            context.sendBroadcast(smsReceiveIntent);
```

and in the activity where you can update the listview:

```
    // Sets up the smsreceiver broadcastreceiver
private void setupSmsReceiver() {
    smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, final Intent intent) {

            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive smsReceiver");

            if (getActivity() != null) {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "runOnUiThread");
                        String uri = intent.getStringExtra("newSMS");
                        addToList(uri);
                        smsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    };
    getActivity().registerReceiver(smsReceiver, new IntentFilter(BlacklistConstants.smsFilter));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to use a ContentObserver in the class that hosts the list, like this
(NOTE: this code goes inside a fragment)

```
    private static final int REFRESH_PAGES = 1;
    private static final int CHANGE_CURRENT_SET = 2;
    private myCustomObserver mContentObserver;


 //utility function to set de observer
// register a un content observer to know that the content has changed
private void registerContentObserver(int myId) {
    Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "registerContentObserver, myId=" + myId);
    if (mContentObserver != null) {
        getActivity().getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(
                mContentObserver);
    }
    mContentObserver = new MyCustomObserver (mHandler);
    getActivity().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
            yourUri, true,
            mContentObserver);
}
```

...... this is the content observer

```
class MyCustomObserver extends ContentObserver {
    public MyCustomObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "MyCustomObserver");
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        Log.i(DEBUG_TAG, "onChange, selfChange==" + selfChange);
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(REFRESH_PAGES);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
    };

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri) {
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "onChange, selfChange==" + selfChange + ", uri=="
                + uri.toString());
        final Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(REFRESH_PAGES);
        mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
        super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I also need a handler :

```
public Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(android.os.Message msg) {
        Log.v(DEBUG_TAG, "mHandler");
        if (isAdded()) {//IMPORTANT if you are in a fragment
            switch (msg.what) {
                case REFRESH_PAGES:
                    getLoaderManager().getLoader(0).forceLoad();
                    break;
                case CHANGE_CURRENT_SET:
                    firstTime = true;
                    doYourStaff();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
};
```

in the Content Provider you need something like :

```
                getContext().getContentResolver()
                    .notifyChange(yourUri, null);
```

e voilà ...

Comment: Does this imply that I need to create my own custom contentprovider?

Comment: When you use a content provider you need an URI, so you need to register this URI in the content provider so your content observer is notified. Like this:        getActivity().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
                theURI-you_use_to_acces_the_content_provider, true,
                mContentObserver);

Comment: I understand but when I get a new message I need to requery the uri and find out what is changed. You don't get the changed uri if you use the default contentprovider of android? Or am I wrong?